# Product custom attribute import with CSV Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, csv, custom-attributes, product-import

I am trying to **import product with `CSV`**  in **Magento2**. In the first case, all attributes are default attributes so import works fine.

Now In the second case I have added some custom attributes in my **Magento 2.2** and added them to the attribute set, and with that attribute set, I have created the product manually from the backend. Now I have exported that product to view the format of `CSV` file.

In that I found one thing, My all custom attributes were in one column called "**`additional_attributes`**".

So my question is while **importing products** Do I have to add my all custom attributes under "**`additional_attributes`**"?

Or How May I import my custom attributes values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Upload from the default **CSV** generated by **Magento**

Yes, you need to fill all your custom attributes into the single-column named **`additional_attributes_code`**.

Just simply put all your custom attributes in the following way into the column with the name **`additional_attributes_code`** into your imported **`CSV`** file.

```
custom_attribute_code_1="Value_1",custom_attribute_code_2="Value_2",custom_attribute_code_3="Value_3",custom_attribute_code_4="Value_4"
```

After this simply upload your **CSV** file.

2. Upload with some changes into the **CSV** generated from the **Magento**

You also can create different columns with the **`attribute_code`** of your custom attributes & fill the data into it & upload the file. It will work with it as well.

> Note: First upload a single product manually & download the CSV file
> from your admin & do corrections into it only & use only that file for
> uploading/Updating the products.
>
> I will recommend the **First** one because as of you will have more no. of
> attributes & more no of attribute sets you to need to insert more no of
> columns into your CSV file so better would upload it into a single
> column it will reduce your time for this data entry stuff as of you
> are using CSV upload for that intention only.

Hope This will help!

Thank You!

Comment: But is there any alternative for this ?
Like in magento 1.X we were able to upload directly with attribute names.

Answer (score 6):

I have made one more test case and tried to upload with the name of attribute in csv. Instead of "additional_attributes" I have directly added name of a column and tried to upload value of a custom attribute and it worked.

So both ways are working. 
we can specify under "additional_attributes" as well as we can directly give attribute name to upload value of custom attributes.

Comment: Wish if you have included some screenshots. I think your answer is good because it covered both scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to add all custom attributes under **additional_attributes** column.

See below image

[image]

Comment: Is attr1 the attributes code, or the attributes name?

Comment: attr1 is attribute code

Comment: should i use the "add/update" behavior or "replace" behavior? I used "add/update" but it created a new item with the same sku. I'm worry if the "replace" behavior will erase all other attributes values. Thanks!

Comment: @KrisWen If you choose "Replace", it will delete the old product and regenerate the same product with a different id.

Comment: @DineshYadav I'm trying to update the additional_attributes only without deleting the sku and recreate it. how do I achieve it? I try usingadd/update using the same sku in first column and addtional_attributes in 2nd, but it recreate the same sku. thanks

Comment: If you are using add/update then it will not create a new sku. There might be an extra space or something in SKU. Please check properly.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late, but I found a way that is slightly weird way to import configurable products but it works!

1. Make attribute options before adding product: example; Attri 1, Attri 2, Attri 3, -> make it Required value -> save
   you don't have to set it in any attribute list.
2. Make a configurable product and while making the configurations through attribute, add only 1 option. All options should be selectable but dont! Only "Attri 1" in this case. Noww add price and quantity, set it to 1 both, we are gonna change this anyway. Save.
3. Go back to product with "Attri 1", there is now a Add products manually -> Import your products and automatically bind it to a value you just made:

Add a column and use the same  Attribute Code, find this at the options in your made attribute. Overview:

**Attribute code:** attri_i_made_up 
**Values:** Attri 1, Attri 2, Attri 3,

In your import document:

Column name you want products to be connected to: attri_i_made_up
Column values:

- Row 1: Attri 1
- Row 2: Attri 2
- Row 3: Attri 3

---

**Additional important stuff:**

- Values in import csv and backend magento should match 100% or its
  gonna screw you.
- Open the import document with notepad++ to check field separator.
- If products don't stay in the configurable product you probably have a
  mismatch of values.
- The error message always excludes row 1: Row 23 has some errors ->
  its row 24 in your csv.
- Delete products you don't need or if you have a ruined import that
  added -2 -3 SKU's.

I bet I could have explained this way better but hey I'm in a hurry to import products!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late to the show, but if you are, like me, struggling with custom attributes not being imported (and apparently ignored by magento) make sure, the additional attributes column is not quoted in the csv. 
If this collides with other fields that have to be quoted in your import, consider to import the additional_attributes separately in a csv-file only consisting of the column "sku" and the column "additional_attributes" with comma-separated attributes within. (use a semicolon as field separator in the csv)

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> You also can create different columns with the attribute_code of your custom attributes & fill the data into it & upload the file. It will works with it as well.

I have create my csv file like this:

sku;My_First_multichoice_attribute_code;My_Second_multichoice_attribute_code

product_sku;value-A|value-B;value-X|value-Y|value-Z

; - is a field separator

| - separates values of multichoice_attribute

Every value on both attributes had been successfully imported.