# Import Product Dimensions (Length, Width, Height) in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, import, csv

I am trying to import dimension data to a Magento 2.2.6 store.  The Magento attributes are present on the product, but I cannot figure out how to import to these fields.  I have tried `length` and `item_length` (and similar for height and width).  Every time, the import completes "successfully", but the dimensions are not added.

Has anybody found the correct column headings to use for these fields?

[image: Excel Import Sample Settings]

Comment: Are you giving the exact attribute name into the csv file? You can follow [this answer.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201118/product-custom-attribute-import-with-csv-magento-2-2/201130#201130)

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't know the exact attribute name.  These attributes are not listed under the attributes section (that I could find).  They are not in the sample csv that Magento generates.  The only way I can think to find it other than asking is to start digging in the database.

Comment: If it is not available there into the magento attribute section then better first you create the attributes & then try to import them through the csv it will work! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the correct headings to use by searching the attributes table of the database.  Here are the headings to use, in case you find this searching like I was:

```
ts_dimensions_length

ts_dimensions_width

ts_dimensions_height
```

Comment: Ouch...Not sure why my answer is getting down voted without comment.

Comment: because you don't give any explanation why is that so , this is seems like prefix added by some 3th party extension or so , but not default M2 behaviour

Comment: @FireBear Those aren't added by a 3rd party, those are the names of the new dimensional fields from Magento core.